# How To Call A Javascript Function From Inside Jquery When An ID is Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Let's say I have a javascript function called `capturedata();` 
I need to call this function when this button is clicked

```
<button id='yes'></button>
```

For some reasons, I do not want to use any event handler on the html like `onclick='capturedata()'` 
Now I have use Jquery this way

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#yes").click();
  capturedata();
});
```

But this is not working. I need a better way to handle this, and I do not want to use any event handler like onclick on the html. I want the action to happen automatically once the button is clicked.

Comment: That's the click trigger, not the click event handler. I'd suggest reading the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/click

Comment: Hi, you have to add an event listener to your element to be able to act upon such events: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener
jQuery equivalent: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Click is just a wrapper for `on()` now days, so I'd actually suggest using `on()` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost but not quite, you'll need to register `capturedata` as the callback for the click event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#yes").click(capturedata);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Your click method requires a callback function as its first argument

e.g `.click(() => {})`

see [DOCS](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

Note how calling `.click()` will invoke a click event and not listen for one.

Suggestion : use `addEventListener('click', {yourCallback})` see [DOCS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#yes").click(function(){
    capturedata();
    // some code
  });
});
```

Comment: @alex I already accepted the first answer that came which was correct too and it spotted my error.

Comment: As you can see from phuzi's answer, the inner anonymous method is unnecessary.